# Generic table with slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to create a generic table abstract class that I can use to represent collections and reduce boilerplate.

This is my first try:

```
abstract class StringCollectionTable[A](tag: Tag,
                                      name1: String, name2: String,
                                      table: TableQuery[A], idMapper: A => Rep[Long])
extends Table[(Long, String)](tag, name1+"_"+name2) {

def id = column[Long]("ID_"+name1)
def item = column[String](name2)

def pk = primaryKey("pk_"+name1+"_"+name2, (id, item))

def idFK = foreignKey(name1 + "_FK", id, table)(idMapper, onUpdate=ForeignKeyAction.Restrict, onDelete=ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)

override def * : ProvenShape[(Long, String)] = (id, item)
}
```

And it is suposed to be used like:

```
case class Foo(...)
class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Foo](tag, "FOO") {...}
val foos = TableQuery[FooTable]
val mapToId = (t: TableQuery[FooTable]) => t.id


class FooBarTable(tag: Tag)
extends StringCollectionTable(tag, "FOO", "BAR", foos, mapToId)
```

So with this I can store a collection of bar-values related with one foo.

In IntellJ IDEA this code seems ok. But when I run the app I get the error:

```
inferred type arguments [slick.lifted.Rep[Long],Nothing,A,Nothing] do not conform to method foreignKey's type parameter bounds [P,PU,TT <: slick.lifted.AbstractTable[_],U]
```

In line:

```
    def idFK = foreignKey(name1 + "_FK", id, table)(idMapper, onUpdate=ForeignKeyAction.Restrict, onDelete=ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)
```

I've been doing some search and I can't find the problem. It's my first Slick project and I'm a bit lost.

Someone can tell my the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type Parameter `A` should be subtype of `Table` implies `A <: Table[_]`

Declare your `StringCollectionTable` like this

```
abstract class StringCollectionTable[A <: Table[_]](tag: Tag, ...) extends ... {
  ...
  override def * = (id, item)
}
```

Comment: It "works" with [A <: AbstractTable[_]], I get a new error:

No matching Shape found.
Slick does not know how to map the given types.
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
  Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
     Source type: A
   Unpacked type: U
     Packed type: Any

Comment: @AlejandroTrujilloCaballero  def * has to defined properly

Comment: Is defined as `override def * : ProvenShape[(Long, String)] = (id, item)` I can't see the problem in that line

Comment: Leave the `*` implementation to the subtypes ... the concrete types @AlejandroTrujilloCaballero

Comment: @AlejandroTrujilloCaballero ... Leaving implementation of `*` method to the class with implements with class is one way to go

Comment: Same error with `*` in the child class, but it works with the `def idFK = ...` line in the child class!!! Thanks!

Comment: @AlejandroTrujilloCaballero edited the answer . Please check now